# Hichcharts - Custom legend css not getting displayed in Print Chart download functionality

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, highcharts

I want to use custom legend in chart. So added some css as per requirement to render custom legends. It getting displayed properly on web. But when I try to download it using **Print Chart** option, it's not displaying custom legend design in downloaded document. In other download options it's working fine except **Print Chart**. I have tried many solutions but nothing works. Even I have tried with Highcharts jsfiddle example as well with custom legend, it's not working. 
Please refer example here. https://jsfiddle.net/DipaliShinde/ep73vqun/1/ (In this example it's not showing css as expected for **Series1** legend with background color)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
exporting: {
    chartOptions: { // specific options for the exported image
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        }
    },
    fallbackToExportServer: false
},

title: {
    text: 'Offline export'
},
legend: {
        enabled: true,
            layout: 'vertical',
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'right',
            useHTML: true,
            floating: false,
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            x: -40,
            y: 10,
            //maxHeight: 320,
            itemMarginBottom: 20,
    labelFormatter: function () {

                return '<div><div style="padding-right: 5px;color: #666666;text-align:center;">Text 123<span style="padding-left: 5px;font-size: 12px;font-weight: 300;color: #999999;">(16.78%)</span></div>' +
                    '<div style="background:' + this.color + ';height:20px; width:120px;text-align:center;color:white;font-weight:300;font-size: 10px;line-height:20px;">'
                    + this.name + '</div></div>';
            }
},
subtitle: {
    text: 'Click the button to download as PNG, JPEG, SVG or PDF'
},

chart: {
    type: 'area'
},

xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
},

series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 126.0, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}]
```

});

Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: when some one clicks on PrintChart  you want to show css ???

Comment: PrintChart document should render with correct css properties applied to custom legend same as it displaying on web.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable experimental `allowHTML` option, but without online export server it works only for SVG vector image. You can find more information here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5985

```
exporting: {
    allowHTML: true,
    chartOptions: {...},
    //fallbackToExportServer: false
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2nvpfgyo/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.allowHTML

Answer (score 0):

With allowHTML, it works for all download option except Print Chart. For Print Chart its not rendering legend same as other download options. Attaching here screenshot.

[Print Chart Legend Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNwDZ.png)